# MATLAB - Why does this not work?

Tags: matlab

I'm stumped. What is going on with MATLAB's syntax?

```
clear all;

dx = .1;
x=-2:dx:2;
f=zeros(length(x),1);
int_f=zeros(length(x),1);
for n=1:length(x)
    f(n)=x(n).^2;
    int_f(n) = f(n)*dx+int_f(n);
end
plot(x,int_f(n));
```

Comment: What happens when you do this and what do you expect to happen

Comment: Define "not working." In exact terms.

Comment: The plot is a nonsensical dataset that is 1 dimensional. This should not be the case. That code is implementing an integral of x^2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should be plotting that using `plot(x,int_f);` that way you plot the two arrays rather than one array against one single number.

Also your integral step is wrong, it should be `int_f(n) = f(n)*dx+int_f(n-1)` except for the first run, where it should be `int_f(n) = f(n)*dx`

Answer (score 2):

Because in `plot(x,int_f(n));`, `x` is a row vector, but `int_f(n)` is a scalar value. You should be plotting a vector against a vector.